# How to remove or increase selected decoration in NavigationBar

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, navbar

How can I remove or increase the decoration of the selected item in the NavigationBar in flutter?

```
NavigationBar(
        elevation: 0,
        selectedIndex: navIndex,
        onDestinationSelected: (index) => setState(() {
          navIndex = index;
        }),
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        labelBehavior: NavigationDestinationLabelBehavior.alwaysHide,
        destinations: const [
          NavigationDestination(
            icon: Text('Your subscriptions'),
            label: '',
          ),
          NavigationDestination(
            icon: Text('Upcoming bills'),
            label: '',
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

image of decoration

[image]

Comment: Which navigation bar is this? Dart BottomNavigation bar or something else ?

Comment: @HeshanSandeepa Just NavigationBar [link](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/NavigationBar-class.html)

Comment: You can use BottomNavigationBar instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, the NavigationDestination icon has to be an Icon() widget.
But in your case, it's text. That's why the text exceeds the highlighted area.

```
NavigationDestination(
        icon: <This has to be a Icon>
        label: '',
),
```

Icon will use 'NavigationBarThemeData.iconTheme' , if 'NavigationBarThemeData' not present , icon will use 'IconThemeData'. In both cases, I couldn't find a way to change the size of the highlighted area.

You could do something like this, it will do the job but not that smooth.

```
  int _selectedIndex = 0; // local variable



      NavigationDestination(
        icon: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                color: _selectedIndex == 0 ? Colors.blue.shade100 : Colors.transparent,
                shape: BoxShape.rectangle),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Text('Your subscriptions'),
            )),
        label: 'Your subscriptions',
      ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue solved ii by adding NavigationBarThemeData().copyWith and giving the selected a transparent hex value

```
navigationBarTheme: const NavigationBarThemeData().copyWith(
                indicatorColor: const Color(0X00000000)
            )
```

The resulting nav would look something like this

```
NavigationDestination(
                    selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.home_filled,color: Colors.grey[700]),
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.home_outlined,),
                    label: 'Home',
                  )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using BottomNavigationBar,this can be used to change the color,textstyle and font size of the contents in navigation bar.

```
BottomNavigationBar(
selectedItemColor: Colors.white
selectedLabelStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
selectedFontSize: 12,
ontap:(){...}
)
```